Is the word "tausend" (thousand) a loan-word from English or a native word? If it's native, why doesn't it start with 'd'?
Obviously, the rule is that, in native words, English 'th' corresponds to German 'd': "three"-"drei", "thick"-"dick", "thin"-"dünn", "this"-"das", "that"-"dass", "there"-"da", "bath"-"Bad", "thirst"-"Durst", "thank"-"danken", "think"-"denken", "thing"-"Ding", "brother"-"Bruder", "thou"-"du", "then"-"dann...
So, why doesn't this rule apply to the word "tausend" (thousand)? Is "tausend" maybe a loan-word from English "thousand", with 'th' being borrowed as 't'?

It's not a loanword from English. The English and the German word have a common root, so none of them is a loanword of the other. They are twins that derived from the same root. For more details consult this question: Wha tausend (not dausend)?

Was ist mit "thong/Zunge", "theme/Thema"?

@userunknown: Das kannst du sehr leicht hier erfahren.

@HubertSchölnast: Super Idee! Frag da doch mal, was eine rhetorische Frage ist.

@userunknown: Woran soll jemand erkennen, dass das eine rhetorische Frage sein soll? Wenn du darauf aufmerksam machen willst, dass die genannten beispiele Ausnahmen sind, dann formuliere das bitte nicht als Frage, sondern als Aussage.

Die Wortpaare sind Belege, dass die Vermutung, das "Th" entspräche dem deutschen "D" keine Regel ist. Das Wort "Tausend" ist offensichtlich nicht alleine.
